# Mysql query with current date using timestamp and condition?

Tags: mysql

Can I write a mysql query with a condition and the current date for example with a different timestamp? For example when I have an event and an interval and I want the same query but slightly different order by or group by. Basically I'm looking for a function that in time it returns slightly different results. An example is a graph where I have probabilities and then I have a random number generator between 0 and 1 and I loop through each edge to select the correct edge.

```
    x = random([0.0, 1.0])
    for i in 0..n
    if x < probabilities[i]
       choose(i)
       break
     else
        x -= probabilities[i]
     end
```

Comment: You need to explain your need better.  And review the [MySQL DATE functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html) to see the date addition and subtraction options available.

Comment: no idea what are you asking... please make your question more clear, give an example etc

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understood you correctly but `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` returns sligtly diffirent result   in time :)